# AS3: Arabic Embed Fonts

Tags: actionscript-3, text, arabic

I am using as3 and trying to use embed fonts with Arabic text but it doesn't work 
So is there a way that I can access from .tff file the shape of the character or make it works using embed fonts

As using system fonts works but at same time its bad as on some machines it is reverted so I want to use embed font

Hope anyone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found code by some one to change the input arabic text to the correct shape based on the position in text and I modified it to work perfectly with my code :)

here the AS3 code file: http://www.akhalifa.com/testing/ArabicAS3File/ArabicStringUtils.as

and here an example on how to use it: http://www.akhalifa.com/testing/ArabicAS3File/Main.as

Answer (score 1):

You can use any arabic/persian input language like [Maryam4](http://mihangraph.com/2762/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3-%D9%85%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%85-%D9%86%D8%B3%D8%AE%D9%87-5-%D8%A8%D8%AF%D9%88%D9%86-%D9%86%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B2.html)
then write your sentence in this program after that copy it and paste in your code
also as @Goran Mottram said embed your font (for this situation if you use Maryam you must select F_fonts)
but noticed that in your code if you paste your arabic language it shows you wired character like ÂMoø , but dont worry if you publish you see a correct arabic word with rtl support

Comment: if you have a problem tell me to say more inforamation

Answer (score 0):

If you have the font installed on your system, make sure to import the font into your library and tick the box "Export for ActionScript" and give it an appropriate name, say `MyArabicFont`, then bind it to textfield using the following code:

```
// create the font
var myFont:Font = new MyArabicFont();

// assign to textformat
var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
myTextFormat.font = myFont.fontName;

// assign to textfield          
var myTextField:TextField = new TextField();
myTextField.defaultTextFormat = myTextFormat;
myTextField.embedFonts = true;
myTextField.text = "Hello, world";
this.addChild(myTextField);
```

Comment: I have done that and all I get is white screen :'( nothing appear

Comment: @user1147825 Sorry, my previous snippet of code had a few lines missing and a few typos. Try it now, but with some actual Arabic text and not "Hello, world".

Comment: thanks goran I have figured out the problem when I use a font contain arabic the problem that the arabic letter have more than one form depending on its position in the word which differs from english so I had to make an algorithm to concatenate that and transform every character :) thnx inadvance :)

Comment: No worries :) Glad you figured it out.